# How to vectorize the code in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization, euclidean-distance

I have some Cluster Centers and some Data Points. I want to calculate the distances as below (norm is for Euclidean distance):

```
            costsTmp = zeros(NObjects,NClusters);
            lambda = zeros(NObjects,NClusters);
            for clustclust = 1:NClusters
                for objobj = 1:NObjects
                    costsTmp(objobj,clustclust) = norm(curCenters(clustclust,:)-curPartData(objobj,:),'fro');
                    lambda(objobj,clustclust) = (costsTmp(objobj,clustclust) - log(si1(clustclust,objobj)))/log(si2(objobj,clustclust));
                end
            end
```

How can I vectorize this snippet?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    Difference = zeros(NObjects,NClusters);
    costsTmp = zeros(NObjects,NClusters);
    lambda = zeros(NObjects,NClusters);
    for clustclust = 1:NClusters
    repeated_curCenter = repmat(curCenter(clustclust,:), NObjects, 1); 
    % ^^ This creates a repeated matrix of 1 cluster center but with NObject
    % rows. Now, dimensions of repeated_curCenter equals that of curPartData

    Difference(:,clustclust) = repeated_curCenter - curPartData;
    costsTmp(:,clustclust) = sqrt(sum(abs(costsTmp(:,clustclust)).^2, 1)); %Euclidean norm
    end
```

The approach is to try and make the matrices of equal dimensions. You could eliminate the present for loop also by extending this concept by making 2 3D arrays like this:

costsTmp = zeros(NObjects,NClusters);
        lambda = zeros(NObjects,NClusters);

```
    %Assume that number of dimensions for data = n
    %curCenter's dimensions = NClusters x n
    repeated_curCenter = repmat(curCenter, 1, 1, NObjects);
    %repeated_curCenter's dimensions = NClusters x n x NObjects

    %curPartData's dimensions = NObject x n
    repeated_curPartData = repmat(curPartData, 1, 1, NClusters);
    %repeated_curPartData's dimensions = NObjects x n x NClusters

    %Alligning the matrices along similar dimensions. After this, both matrices
    %have dimensions of NObjects x n x NClusters
    new_repeated_curCenter = permute(repeated_curCenter, [3, 2, 1]);

    Difference = new_repeated_curCenter - repeated_curPartData;

    Norm = sqrt(sum(abs(Difference)).^2, 2); %sums along the 2nd dimensions i.e. n
    %Norm's dimensions are now NObjects x 1 x NClusters. 

    Norm = permute(Norm, [1, 3, 2]);
```

Here, Norm is kinda like costsTmp, just with an extra dimensions. I havent provided the code for lambda. I dont know what lambda is in the question's code too.

Answer (score 2):

This vectorization can be done very elegantly (if I may say so) using `bsxfun`. **No need** for any `repmat`s

```
costsTemp = bsxfun( @minus, permute( curCenters, [1 3 2] ), ...
                            permute( curPartData, [3 1 2] ) );
% I am not sure why you use Frobenius norm, this is the same as Euclidean norm for vector
costsTemp = sqrt( sum( costsTemp.^2, 3 ) ); % now we have the norms
lambda = costsTmp -reallog(si1)./reallog(si2);
```

you might need to play a bit with the order of the `permute` dimensions vector to get the output exactly the same (in terms of transposing it).

Comment: Would you please describe what is the meaning of [1 2 3] or [3 1 2]. My dataset domain is not in 2d or 3d space. As I have tested, regular norm does not (without 'fro') does not return the exact value I need always!

Comment: @remo from your code it would seem that `curCenters` is a  2D array of size CxD: C centers with dimension D. It would also seem `curPartData` is a 2D array of size PxD: P points in D dimensions. In order to compute all CxP differences the code above permute the two 2D matrices into Cx1xD and 1xPxD 3D matrices with singelton dimensions. The `bsxfun` takes advantage of this singleton dimension and compute a CxPxD array of differences. This 3D result is saved in `costsTemp`. Squaring it and summing over the third dimension gives back the desired result.

Comment: @remo Is this solution good for you? Is there a reason you do not accept it?